# What is the maximum Obelisk level?

Tags: destiny-2

With the release of [Season 9 Season of Dawn](https://www.bungie.net/7/en/Seasons/SeasonOfDawn) a number of planets have had Obelisks added to them, which tie into the Sundial on Mercury.

Donating your Polarized Fractaline will rank up an Obelisk unlocking extra benefits.

What is the maximum rank for an Obelisk?

There is a Triumph to get 40 ranks

> Global Resonance
>   Increase the Resonance Rank of any obelisks.

..and I have seen bonuses for Rank 11, so it doesn't cap out at 10. With 4 Obelisks x 10 Ranks for the 40 Global Resonance Triumph.

Do they just keep ranking up as long as you have seasonal currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rewards from the obelisks cap out at level 11, so you need 8800 polarized fractaline to max all of the obelisks out. After that you can keep turning them in 200 polarized fractaline for 1 timelost engram each or better yet pick up the timelost bounties for 10 polarized fractaline each and farm for random rolls on the timelost weapons.